# Getting the value of textarea inside form

Tags: javascript

I want to get the value of this textarea inside form and copy the the value to another textarea outside form using javascript. How should I do that? here's my textarea...

```
<form>
    <textarea id="tpName" name="tpName" onchange="tpName(this)" style="margin-top: -9px; width: 275px; height: 40px;"></textarea>
</form>

<textarea id="copytpName" name="copytpName" style="margin-top: -9px; width: 275px; height: 40px;"></textarea>
```

Whenever I type a value in textarea inside form, I also want to update the value of textarea outside form.

Comment: On what event? Keydown, keyup, focus, blur, after x seconds? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried onchange, onkeyup but nothing happens. this is my script. function `tpName(data){
    document.getElementById("copytpName").value = data.value;
   }`

Comment: One thing. When I'm removing the form tag, it works perfect. My only problem is when the textarea is inside the form tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for jQuery as some others have posted in their answer. Simply don't name your function the same thing you use for IDs and form names and it works:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dggML/1/)**

```
<form>
    <textarea id="ttpName" name="ttpName" onchange="tpName(this)" style="margin-top: -9px; width: 275px; height: 40px;"></textarea>
</form>
<textarea id="copytpName" name="copytpName" style="margin-top: -9px; width: 275px; height: 40px;"></textarea>
function tpName(data) {
    document.getElementById("copytpName").value = data.value;
}
```

I changed your textarea to `<textarea id="ttpName" name="ttpName" ...`

Comment: It working. Save my day. Sorry didn't know about it may reflect on names.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this in javascript,

HTML

```
<form>
<textarea id="tpName" name="tpName" onkeyup="copyThis(this);" style="margin-top: -9px; width: 275px; height: 40px;"></textarea>
</form>

<textarea id="copytpName" name="copytpName" style="margin-top: -9px; width: 275px; height: 40px;"></textarea>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function copyThis(txObj) {
    document.getElementById("copytpName").value = txObj.value;   
}
```

Note: You need to change the function name. The function name matches with the textarea name, so its creating the issue in your case.

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/CZCnx/2/

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
var text = document.getElementById("tpName").value;

$("#copytpName").attr("value", text);
```

Comment: The question isn't tagged with jQuery so you might to explain that your answer requires it.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the code here, it uses jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/5B6KC/1/

CODE:

```
$("#tpName").keyup(function(){
    $("#copytpName").val($(this).val());
})
```