# How to get the current edited value of a textarea when onblur occurs?

Tags: javascript, dom, textarea, onblur

I want to grab the current, post edited value of my textarea elements when onblur occurs.  Despite having changed the content, the DOM keeps giving me the original content.  For example...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>blur updates</title>
  <script>
    viewContent = function(id) {
      console.log(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Edit one, then click in two. Does the value change in the console?
    <br/> No, it does not.
  </p>
  <br/>
  <form>
    <textarea id="1" onblur="viewContent('1')" cols="24" rows="4">one</textarea>
    <textarea id="2" onblur="viewContent('2')" cols="24" rows="4">two</textarea>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Any edits to the textareas are not reflected in the console.  How do I get the current content?

Comment: ues `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: There's no reason for `viewContent` to take an argument. Inside the function, change: `document.getElementById(id)` to `this`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the value of textarea inside form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317866/getting-the-value-of-textarea-inside-form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>blur updates</title>
  <script>
    viewContent = function(id) {
      console.log(document.getElementById(id).value);
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Edit one, then click in two. Does the value change in the console?
    <br/> No, it does not.
  </p>
  <br/>
  <form>
    <textarea id="1" onblur="viewContent('1')" cols="24" rows="4">one</textarea>
    <textarea id="2" onblur="viewContent('2')" cols="24" rows="4">two</textarea>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Further readings:-

[`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/value)

[`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)